# declaration of construcor shadows a parameter

Tags: c++, конструктор

Есть небольшая nested-структура:

```
struct decode_bunch_ctrl_t
{
    pure_smb2_header::flags_t   request_flags;
    bool                        flags_set;
    uint64_t                    msg_id;

    decode_bunch_ctrl_t(pure_smb2_header::flags_t request_flags_, uint64_t msg_id_) 
        : request_flags(request_flags_), flags_set(true), msg_id(msg_id_) {}
    decode_bunch_ctrl_t()
        : request_flags(pure_smb2_header::flags_t()), flags_set(false), msg_id(0) {}
    operator bool () { return flags_set && msg_id; }
};
```

При этом структура `pure_smb2_header::flags_t` определена так:

```
struct flags_t
{
    static const uint8_t PRIORITY_MASK = 0b111;

    uint32_t    reserved1:4;
    uint32_t    dfs_operations:1;
    uint32_t    replay_operation:1;
    uint32_t    reserved2:2;

    uint32_t    reserved3:16;

    uint32_t    server_to_redir:1;
    uint32_t    async_command:1;
    uint32_t    related_operations:1;
    uint32_t    signed_packet:1;
    uint32_t    priority_mask:3;
    uint32_t    reserved4:1;
}
```

При инициализации объекта конструктором без параметров выдается ошибка компилятора:

```
error: declaration of ‘smb2_subdecoder::decode_bunch_ctrl_t dctrl_bunch’ shadows a parameter
  917 |     decode_bunch_ctrl_t dctrl_bunch;
```

Но никаких параметров при создании объекта не затеняется. В чем проблема?

Версия компилятора:

```
gcc version 9.2.1 20191102 (Ubuntu 9.2.1-17ubuntu1~18.04.1)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я могу предположить, что вы не туда смотрите, похоже что вы в функции создали локальную переменную с названием, совпадающим с названием параметра. А 917 это номер строчки, где создан такой параметр.

[Вот пример из Google](https://techoverflow.net/2013/02/03/gcc-error-declaration-of-shadows-a-parameter/#:%7E:text=However%2C%20somewhere%20in%20the%20function,you%20shadow%20a%20function%20argument.)

Comment: Так и есть.
Поправлю вас:
> 917 это номер строчки, где создана такая переменная.